# Linux C Programming - FTP server won't respond through sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ftp

So I am trying to make my own FTP client, I was able to connect to a ftp server and get the "220" response code but when I try to send ANY command the recv function just gets blocked. This is my code:

I have tried multiple free ftp servers and I was able to connect to all of them and get a 220 response code but from there I couldn't communicate with them at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ERR(str) {printf("%s errno says: %s\n", str, strerror(errno));}

int getFTPcode(int sock){
    char response[2550];
    if(0 > recv(sock, response, 2550, 0)){
        ERR("ftp response failed to recv");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%s\n", response);
    while(1){
        char msg[2000];
        printf("Enter command:");
        scanf("%s", msg);
        if(0 > send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0)){
            ERR("failed to send to server");
            return 0;
        }

        if(0 > recv(sock, response, 2000, 0)){
            ERR("failed to recv from server");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Response: %s\n", response);
    }


    printf("%s\n", response);
}

int connToOrig(char* ip, short port){

    struct sockaddr_in addrin;
    memset(&addrin, '0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addrin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addrin.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addrin.sin_addr) < 0){
        ERR("inet_pton failed");
        return 0;
    }

    int sock;
    if(0 > (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))){
        ERR("socket() failed");
        return 0;
    }

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addrin, sizeof(addrin)) < 0){
        ERR("connection to the origin server failed");
        return 0;
    }


    printf("connection succesfull\n");
    getFTPcode(sock);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    connToOrig(argv[1], 21);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well jokes on me, the problem was that I was not appending '\n' to the messages that I was sending to the ftp server